# Two problems on my WordPress installation

Tags: plugins, posts, updates

First problem is I can't scroll on creation post page, same with disabled all plugins.

Second problem is I have already an update notification in menu but no update on update page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further info, hard to say. But I would

- update WP again (even if you already did, just to make sure it is fully updated)
- change to one of the 'twenty' themes (you can do that by temporarily renaming the current theme's file folder).

Since you state that you disabled all plugins (but not how; I assume that you renamed the plugin folder?) it would seem that the plugins are not the problem. That's why I suspect the theme - and re-doing the WP update couldn't hurt.